# How to open multiple forms at once

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I spawn multiple forms at once without having the user exit out of the each one before the next is shown?

```
public static void RepeatAction(int repeatCount, Action action)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < repeatCount; i++)
        action();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RepeatAction(10, () => {
        Random random = new Random();
        int x = random.Next(0, 100);
        Random random1 = new Random();
        int y = random.Next(0, 100);

        var form = new Form1
        {
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
            ShowInTaskbar = false,
            Location = new Point(x, y)
        };
        form.ShowDialog();
    });
```

Currently this works by opening one form, user clicks out of that form, then opens a new one. How would I make ten forms open all at once?

Comment: Are you sure the form locations are not exactly the same?

Comment: They are not exactly the same. They are randomly spawned via random number location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1. The main issue is that the `ShowDialog()` method blocks until the form being shown is closed.
2. Related to the first issue is that your program has no message-pumping loop. This is normally provided in the default Winforms template by the call to `Application.Run()` at the end of the `Program.Main()` method. In your example, the `ShowDialog()` method provides this loop, but of course using that has other problems (see first issue :) ).
3. You create a new `Random` object before each time you get a new random number. Not only does this invalidate whatever assurances `Random` gives you regarding even distribution of random numbers, you can often wind up with exactly the same number over and over, because the code can execute so fast that the default seed for the `Random` class doesn't change (it's based on the current tick count).

Here is an example that actually works:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        ShowForms();
        Application.Run();
    }

    public static void RepeatAction(int repeatCount, Action action)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < repeatCount; i++)
            action();
    }

    static void ShowForms()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int formCount = 0;

        RepeatAction(10, () =>
        {
            formCount++;

            int x = random.Next(0, 100);
            int y = random.Next(0, 100);

            Form1 form = new Form1
            {
                StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
                ShowInTaskbar = false,
                Location = new Point(x, y)
            };

            form.FormClosed += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (--formCount > 0)
                {
                    return;
                }

                Application.ExitThread();
            };

            form.Show();
        });
    }
}
```

Notes:

- You may notice that the `Main()` method is almost identical to what the default Winforms template provides. I recommend *always* starting with this template, and making minimal changes to it.
- The default template creates a form instance and passes it to `Application.Run()`. But this approach makes that form the "main form", and when that form is closed, the entire program exits. In the example above, the program will exit only when *all* of the opened forms are closed. It does this by not passing any form instance to `Application.Run()` (which puts control of application exit into your hands), and then keeping a counter that tracks how many forms are opened. When the counter gets back down to zero, `Application.ExitThread()` is called, which causes the `Application.Run()` method to return, allowing the program to exit.
- I addresses the random number issue by simply moving initialization of the `Random` object out of your form-creating loop, doing it just once, and reusing the same object for each random number desired.
- I don't know what the point of the `RepeatAction()` method is (doesn't seem to add anything useful above what a plain-vanilla `for` loop would), but I left it in there for consistency with your original code.

Comment: Thanks. The Repeat Action was needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try form.Show();

```
public static void RepeatAction(int repeatCount, Action action)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < repeatCount; i++)
        action();
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RepeatAction(10, () =>
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int x = random.Next(0, 100);
        Random random1 = new Random();
        int y = random.Next(0, 100);

        var form = new Form1
        {
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
            ShowInTaskbar = false,
            Location = new Point(x, y)
        };
        form.Show();

    });
```

Comment: Great to hear that @RohanPas

Comment: @RohanPas, If this solved your problem you should mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: I don't see how this could possibly address the question. There's no message-pump. Each form might appear, but it won't be able to update itself or interact with the user.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Do you know how to make it update or interact?

Comment: @RohanPas: yes, I do. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42825307)

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx):

> You can use `ShowDialog()` to display a modal dialog box in your application. When this method is called, the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed.

Unless you want to spawn a different thread for each form, you should use [`Control.Show()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show(v=vs.110).aspx)